# UILabel numberOfLines = 0 not working

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

I try to make a label with several lines, but it doesnt work, everytime I get only 1 line and a part of string instead two lines

This is the view that I have in which the label is installed

```
class ProfileTextView: UIView {

var titleLabel:UILabel = {
    var label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont(name: "VAGWorld-Bold", size: 14)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    return label
}()

var textView:UITextView = {
    var textView = UITextView()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
    textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    return textView
}()

var editButton:UIButton = {
    var button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Редактировать", forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 5/255, green: 195/255, blue: 142/255, alpha: 1), forState: .Normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 10)
    button.tag = 1
    return button
}()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(titleLabel)
    titleLabel.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topAnchor, constant: 0).active = true
    titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(leadingAnchor, constant: 0).active = true
    titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(trailingAnchor).active = true
    titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(18).active = true

    addSubview(textView)
    textView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4).active = true
    textView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(leadingAnchor, constant: -5).active = true
    textView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(trailingAnchor, constant: 0).active = true

    addSubview(editButton)
    editButton.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(textView.bottomAnchor,constant: 0).active = true
    editButton.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(textView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).active = true
    editButton.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(16).active = true
    editButton.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(bottomAnchor).active = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

This is the viewcontroller inside which I insert view with label

```
class ProfileViewController:UIViewController {

lazy var sixThingsBlock: ProfileTextView = {
    var block = ProfileTextView()
    block.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    block.titleLabel.text = "Here goes large text that doesnt fits to one line and has to be transferred to second line"
    block.textView.text = "Some text also"
    block.textView.editable = false
    block.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProfileViewController.editHandler(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    block.editButton.tag = 5
    return block
}()

func viewDidload() {

  scrollView.addSubview(sixThingsBlock)
    sixThingsBlock.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).active = true
    sixThingsBlock.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).active = true
    sixThingsBlock.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(favoritesBlock.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).active = true
    sixThingsBlockHeight = sixThingsBlock.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(70)
    sixThingsBlockHeight!.active = true

}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you try to call sizeToFit on the label ?

Comment: You have constrained the height of the label. That wonif you want dynamic height

Comment: Remove `titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(18).active = true` as height should be calculated intrinsically.

Comment: Are you trying to have self-sizing cells?